# Cannot install Visual Studio on Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8.1

I am trying to install Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop on Windows 8.1 on my Lenovo IdeaPad.

Immediately upon trying to install, it crashes and I get the following error:
[image: screenshot]

**"Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop - ENU with Update 4 has stopped working."**

I meet all of the listed requirements and this is my first time trying to install VS, so not sure what to do.

Log file in C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp:
http://justpaste.it/inp4

Comment: Even if logged in as an Admin have you tried right click **Run Setup.exe as Admin**?

Comment: Yes I have tried that - no difference.

Comment: Are you using the WebInstaller or have you downloaded the iso? Tried both? Also [see this similar Q on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/791745/i-cannot-install-any-version-of-visual-studio-in-windows-8-1), can you try those steps and report back with the log file. ps Just unmount the iso using WinRar if you download the full setup package.

Comment: WebInstaller, I haven't downloaded the ISO/burnt to a disc to install.  I'll try this, but why should this make a difference?

Comment: Tried the procedures in the link you shared Jeremy, that didn't work either though.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the log file.

Comment: I would recommend first to install all updates/reboot. Second, try  to install Visual Studio 2013 Community edition, which is VS 2013 professional and pretty much free to use http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx

Comment: [Visual Studio installation Tips](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/60f71a54-506e-4c70-be98-e993ce6d1ddf/visual-studio-installation-tips?forum=vssetup) - try these **Disable your Anti Virus software** and **Update your computer (Windows)**